# android app issue app is not responding wait or close

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am developing a new app that gets data from a local database and uploads it to the Cloud but, after some time, it shows a prompt that the app is not responding.

I have reviewed the `logcat` debugger log but can not identify the issue. I am using `gennymotion` as virtual device to test the app.

Can anyone help me resolve this?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SmartScheduler.JobScheduledCallback,NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    String str;
    ProgressBar pb;
    TextView textView;


    private static final int JOB_ID = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String JOB_PERIODIC_TASK_TAG = "io.hypertrack.android_scheduler_demo.JobPeriodicTask";

    String Ip="";
    String Interval="";

    private String intervalInMillisEditText;

    JSONArray jsonArray;

    static final String UrlPost = "serverIp";
    final String TenantId = "Specific string";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Progress bar code is here
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //for the textView of loading...
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //nevigations
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);



        //get the interval values from Database
        LoadDatabaseData();
    }


    public void LoadDatabaseData(){
        List<IpAddressInverval> listIp = IpAddressInverval.listAll(IpAddressInverval.class);
        for (IpAddressInverval ips:listIp) {
            Ip= ips.getIpAddress();
            Interval = ips.getInterval();
            System.out.println("Ip "+Ip);
            System.out.println("Interval is "+Interval);
        }
    }



    public  void gotoServicePage(View view){
        //get the interval values from Database
        LoadDatabaseData();

//        Button btnstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//        btnstart.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        if(Ip.matches("")  || Interval.matches("")) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill the Parametters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

//        if(Interval.matches("")){
//
//            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Fill the Parametters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
//        }
        else
        {

       // CallApi();

        SmartScheduler jobScheduler = SmartScheduler.getInstance(this);

        // Check if any periodic job is currently scheduled
        if (jobScheduler.contains(JOB_ID)) {
            removePeriodicJob();
            return;
        }

        // Create a new job with specified params
        Job job = createJob();
        if (job == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid paramteres specified. " +
                    "Please try again with correct job params.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        // Schedule current created job
        if (jobScheduler.addJob(job)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Job successfully added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        }


    }


    //call the api and get the data

    public void CallApi(){

        String AddressIp = "http://"+Ip+":5700/api/values";

        new AsyncHttpClient().get(AddressIp, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onStart() {
              //  pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                textView.setText("Loading....");

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {


                str= responseString;
                 //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                try {
                    SpliterStringMethod(str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }




        });


    }

    //spli the strinh into the array
    public  void SpliterStringMethod(String values) throws IOException, JSONException {

        //unquote the string for the data..
        values = values.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");

        //split on the baseis of '#'
        String[] lineString = values.split("#");

        for (int i = 0; i < lineString.length; i++) {
            double idTicket = 0;
            System.out.println(lineString[i]);

            String[] valuesString = lineString[i].split(",");
            System.out.println("inner loop");

            //fETCH THE ID FROM DB if ticket exist then update else insert into it
            Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
            List<Ticket> num = ticket.find(Ticket.class, "TICKETNO = " + valuesString[3]);

            if (num.size() != 0) {


                for (Ticket item : num) {
                    System.out.println("Fetching the id= " + item.getId());
                    idTicket = item.getId();

                }
            }


            if (idTicket == 0) {
                Ticket newTicket = new Ticket(Integer.parseInt(valuesString[1]), Integer.parseInt(valuesString[2])
                        , Integer.parseInt(valuesString[3]), Integer.parseInt(valuesString[4]),
                        Integer.parseInt(valuesString[5]));

                newTicket.save();
                System.out.println("Ticket Saved!..");

            } else {
                //update queue id
                Ticket newqueuid = Ticket.findById(Ticket.class, (int) idTicket);
                newqueuid.setPosition_in_queue(Integer.parseInt(valuesString[5])); // modify the values
                newqueuid.save(); // updates the previous entry with new values.
                System.out.println("Ticket Updated!..");
                idTicket = 0;

            }
        }
    }


        //fetch the data from the Database

        public  void getTableData(){
        //call the ticket table to get the values

        List<Ticket> ticketAll = Ticket.listAll(Ticket.class);

        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<ticketAll.size();i++)
        {
            // JSONObject jGroup1 = new JSONObject();
            Map jGroup1 = new LinkedHashMap();
            jGroup1.put("track_no",ticketAll.get(i).getTrack_no());
            jGroup1.put("time_no",ticketAll.get(i).getTime_no());
            jGroup1.put("ticket_no",ticketAll.get(i).getTicket_no());
            jGroup1.put("branch_id",ticketAll.get(i).getBranch_id());
            jGroup1.put("position_in_queue",ticketAll.get(i).getPosition_in_queue());

            jsonArray.put(new Gson().toJson(jGroup1, Map.class));

        }
        String str = POST(UrlPost,"");

    }






    public String POST(String url, String json){

         enableStrictMode();
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient httpclient= null;
             httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();

        try {

            request.setURI(new URI("IP"));

            response = httpclient.execute(request);
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());



        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // 2. make POST request to the given URL
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost();

            // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
             json = jsonArray.toString();
             json = json.replace("\\","").replace("\"{" ,"{").replace("}\"" ,"}");

            String userName ="admin";
            String password = "******";
            String base64EncodedCredentials = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                    (userName + ":" + password).getBytes(),
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);


            httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", base64EncodedCredentials);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("TenantId", TenantId));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("JsonData", json));

            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            httpPost.setURI(new URI(UrlPost));

            response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            boolean responseBody = Boolean.parseBoolean(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            if ( (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()== HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)  && responseBody==true ){

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Updated Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            System.out.println(responseBody+" values is");




        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        // 11. return result
        return result;
    }


    public void enableStrictMode()
    {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }





    //for the time schedular functions

    private Job createJob() {
        int jobType = 3;
        boolean isPeriodic = true;
        Long miliSecondsInterval = Long.parseLong(Interval)*1000;
        intervalInMillisEditText=Long.toString(miliSecondsInterval) ;

        String intervalInMillisString = intervalInMillisEditText;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(intervalInMillisString)) {
            return null;
        }

        Long intervalInMillis = Long.parseLong(intervalInMillisString);
        Job.Builder builder = new Job.Builder(JOB_ID, this, jobType, JOB_PERIODIC_TASK_TAG)

                .setIntervalMillis(intervalInMillis);

        if (isPeriodic) {
            builder.setPeriodic(intervalInMillis);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    private void removePeriodicJob() {

        SmartScheduler jobScheduler = SmartScheduler.getInstance(this);
        if (!jobScheduler.contains(JOB_ID)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No job exists with JobID: " + JOB_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (jobScheduler.removeJob(JOB_ID)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Job successfully removed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onJobScheduled(Context context, final Job job) {
        if (job != null) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
//                    System.out.println("Shahbaz is running");
//                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Job: " + job.getJobId() + " scheduled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CallApi();
                    getTableData();
                }
            });
            Log.d(TAG, "Job: " + job.getJobId() + " scheduled!");


        }
    }

    //nevigation
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.newItem1) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void onResetSchedulerClick(MenuItem item) {
        SmartScheduler smartScheduler = SmartScheduler.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        smartScheduler.removeJob(JOB_ID);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service has been Stoped!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//        Button btnstart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
//        btnstart.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


//        smartJobButton.setText(getString(R.string.schedule_job_btn));
//        smartJobButton.setEnabled(true);
//        smartJobButton.setAlpha(1.0f);
    }

}
```

Comment: without understanding all your Code... but it seems that you handle long time tasks in UI Thread. maybe Try 'ASyncTask' to do this and avoid Data loading or uploading in UI Thread. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ok sir thanks a lot for your response

Comment: @ManuI have used AsynchTask but on HTTP Client it does not getting any response meanwhile i am using smart scheduler and the process is going on beside taking any response